# submit form check if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use a form for signup with a checkbox with 'terms of use'

```
 <form action="/signup/signup_success.html" id="regform" class="form-horizontal" novalidate="novalidate" autocomplete="off">
  <fieldset>
  <div class="checkbox">
                        <label for="agb" id="checkbox_validate" class="hide success">Please accept Terms of Use</label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="agbcheckbox" id="agbcheckbox">
                            Yes <a target="_blank" href="http://example.de">Datenschutzbestimmungen</a>. </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="buttonWrapper">
                        <button type="submit" class="try-button" >
                            Register
                        </button>
                    </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<script>
 //check if checkbox for terms of use is checked or not
 $("#regform").submit(function(event) {
if ($('#agbcheckbox').prop('checked')) {
    $('#checkbox_validate').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
    //checkbox for terms of use is checked
} else {
    //checkbox for terms of use is NOT checked
    $('#checkbox_validate').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
}
  });
</script>
```

if I add "action="/signup/signup_success.html" to my form, the checkbox validation do not work anymore. If I set the action to action="" the validation works correctly. I don´t find the problem. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need

```
event.preventDefault();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ergec/L8Y8s/

Also suggest to read this to better understand the difference between `event.preventDefault` and `return false`

[event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Comment: that is the better option! Thanks Ergec

Answer (score 0):

found the problem - my function missed a return false;

Answer (score 0):

Your validate still works regardless of action='...' exists or not. The difference is that when you have action='...' defined, the browser will post your form as directed. To prevent this happening in the event of validation failure, you call e.preventDefault()

`eg)
    $("#regform").submit(function(e){
      if (.. validation failes ...) {
        .. do your error msg here
        e.preventDefault() // prevent browser to perform default action (in this case submit the form)
      }
    });`